# Mapping of CSS font to font file

Tags: html, css, pdf, fonts

In CSS you can set the `font-weight` to a numerical value from 100-900. The value of 800 is normally mapped to ExtraBold. When I save the web page as a PDF from my browser and open it in Illustrator, it complains that the font is not installed.

[image]

It is looking for `JetBrainsMonoRoman-ExtraBold` which does of course not exist. It should use `JetBrainsMono-ExtraBold`. Setting the `font-family:'JetBrainsMono-ExtraBold'` does not work.

It seems that the CSS/web browser uses the `font-weight` to map to the roman cut. How can you instruct CSS/web browser to use a specific font?

Comment: Acrobat Reader can open and display the PDF file. When opening a PDF in Illustrator, it requires the fonts to be installed on the computer. It does not access the fonts embedded in the PDF itself.